# Kicked for dying too many times on my CS:GO server

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, server-administration

I want to make an MG server with my friends but have encountered a problem. I don't know how to change the number of suicides to an "unlimited" number.

This is a big problem because after someone dies five times ( think) they get kicked for committing suicide too many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there does not seem to be a console command that allows you to turn off just the auto kicking of suicides without using plugins. It appears to be an oversight by Valve when they introduced it in June.

The only workaround using just the console is `mp_autokick 0` but this does disable the kicking of people AFKing or Team Killing.

Comment: Well he did say that it would be for him and his friends, so I don't think there would be too big of an issue with that, right?

Comment: also if you want to unban yourself or someone from your server before the 15 min ban you can go to http://steamidfinder.com/ to find your/their steam 3 id (type your/their custom/default url then hit `looking for steam 3 id?`) and then type `removeid (steamid)` or if that doesnt work type `removealias (their steam name)`. The steam name is case sensitive and if it has spaces you need to put quotes around the whole name.  example: `removeid U:1:123392290` or `removealias "Riperoni Pizza"`